# python (?) placeholders in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have a working MySQL query in python using (?) place holders, my problem is when I add a WHERE clause in the query, with an extra placeholder (?) SQL won't allow it, I think because it groups placeholders so won't allow the 6th placeholder in the where clause.

Here's my code snippet:

```
self.query.prepare("UPDATE tbl_dev (user_id, dev_ref,dev_mac,dev_ka_der_file_path,dev_ds_der_file_path,dev_type) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id=?;")
self.query.bindValue(0, userID)
self.query.bindValue(1, dev_id)
self.query.bindValue(2, dev_mac)
self.query.bindValue(3, dev_ka_cert)
self.query.bindValue(4, dev_ds_cert)
self.query.bindValue(5, dev_type)
self.query.bindValue(6, devID)

self.query.exec_()
```

Basically it won't except the final devID placeholder as I think it's grouping the 6th (devID) with the first group of placeholders.  Is this even possible in Python/MySQL?

Comment: your `update` syntax is incorrect..there shouldn't be `values` specification.

Comment: Thanks vkp, my initial working solution was for a 'select' clause, thanks for pointing out the SQL syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an incorrect syntax as pointed out by @vkp, the working solution was with a select clause, with an update clause there are no grouped values.  Solution is below.

```
self.query.prepare("UPDATE tbl_dev SET user_id=?,dev_ref=?,dev_mac=?,dev_ka_der_file_path=?,dev_ds_der_file_path=?,dev_type=? WHERE id=?;")
self.query.bindValue(0, userID)
self.query.bindValue(1, dev_id)
self.query.bindValue(2, dev_mac)
self.query.bindValue(3, dev_ka_cert)
self.query.bindValue(4, dev_ds_cert)
self.query.bindValue(5, dev_type)
self.query.bindValue(6, devID)

self.query.exec_()
```